# processing, can't hear the sound of a video using Movie library

Tags: java, video, processing, video-processing

Hy Guys,
I am having problems when I want to play a movie using processing because when I grab a frame to apply a filter of a convolution mask I lose the sound. Everything works fine, but I can´t understand while I can hear only second of the sound and then the rest is off.
Here is my code:

```
import processing.video.*;
//DECLARATION OF OBJECT MOVIE
Movie myMovie;

//DECLARATION OF IMAGE SOURCE AND IMAGE FILTERED
PImage imgOriginal, imgFilterContornos;

// CONVOLUTION MASK TO DETECT EDGES
float[][] matrixContorno = { 
{ -1, -1, -1 }, 
{ -1, 8, -1 }, 
{ -1, -1, -1 } };

// DIMENSION OF CONVOLUTION MASK
int matrixsizeContorno = 3;

// OFFSET
int offsetContorno = 128;

final int RED=0, GREEN=1, BLUE=2;

void setup() {
  //LOAD THE VIDEO
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "cartell_cine.mov");
  myMovie.noLoop();
  size(1280, 720);

  myMovie.play();
  frameRate(30);
}

void draw() {

}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie m) {
    m.read();
    //GET THE FRAME
    imgOriginal=m; 
    // I CREATE A NEW IMAGE WITH SAME DIMENSIONS AS ORIGINAL
    imgFilterContornos = createImage(imgOriginal.width, imgOriginal.height, RGB);

    // LOADING PIXELES TO ALLOW ACCESS TO ARRAY pixels[]
    imgOriginal.loadPixels();
    imgFilterContornos.loadPixels();

    for (int x = 0; x < m.width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < m.height; y++) {

        // CALCULATING CONVOLUTION
        int r = convolution(x, y, matrixContorno, matrixsizeContorno, offsetContorno, imgOriginal,RED);
        int g = convolution(x, y, matrixContorno, matrixsizeContorno, offsetContorno, imgOriginal,GREEN);
        int b = convolution(x, y, matrixContorno, matrixsizeContorno, offsetContorno, imgOriginal,BLUE);
        // I GET THE NEW PIXEL
        int loc = x + y * imgOriginal.width;
        imgFilterContornos.pixels[loc] = color(r,g,b);

      }
    } 

    imgFilterContornos.updatePixels();
    set(0,0,imgFilterContornos);


}

// METHOD TO CALCULATE DE SPACIAL CONVOLUTION
int convolution(int x, int y, float[][] matrix, int matrixsize, int offset, PImage img, int canal) {
      float result = 0.0;
      int half = matrixsize / 2;

      // Recorremos la matriz de convolución
      for (int i = 0; i < matrixsize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixsize; j++) {
        // Cálculo del píxel sobre el que estamos trabajando
        int xloc = x + i - half;
        int yloc = y + j - half;
        int loc = xloc + img.width * yloc;

        // We make sure that we take a pixel within the valid range. In this case we are
        // applying replication of nearby pixel values ​​to pixel locations
        // coming out of the image
        loc = constrain(loc, 0, img.pixels.length-1);

        // Calculation of the convolution operation
        // Check the value of the corresponding channel
        if (canal==RED)
          result += ((imgOriginal.pixels[loc] >> 16 & 0xFF) * matrix[i][j]);
        else if (canal==GREEN)
          result += ((imgOriginal.pixels[loc] >> 8 & 0xFF) * matrix[i][j]);
          else if (canal==BLUE)
            result += ((imgOriginal.pixels[loc] & 0xFF) * matrix[i][j]);
        }
      }

      // OFFSET
      result += offset;


      result = constrain(result, 0, 255);


      return (int)result;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the sound only cut-out if you do the **calculate convolution** process? What happens if you comment `//` those 5 lines of code? Also try resizing/position the video and edited version to become side by side just to see what happens to video part (you read pixels only, so there'll be no sound if video itself is not playing).

Comment: Hi VC.One, as you asked, If I comment the 5 lines within the for, the sound works fine, so: Could it be the convolution process? maybe is too much for the pc. On the other hand, in the processing website, I have read "If you want to draw immediately based on the new image, then use the Movie.available() method. "
So, If I change my program using the method Movie.avalible within draw() and use the iterations of itself, then it works but it stores less frames, almost the half. :/